# The align* environment won't ignore text when centering

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

The equation part (ignoring the text) won't center horizontally. Here's my code

```
\begin{align*}
    a_{3k+3}  & = a_{3k+2} + 2a_{3k+1}  \\
    & = a_{3k+1} + 2a_{3k} + 2a_{3k + 1} \\
    & = 3a_{3k+1} + 2a_{3k} \\
    & = 3a_{3k+1} + 2(3m) \hspace{5mm} \text{(by the Induction Hypothesis)} \\ 
    & = 3(a_{3k+1} + 2m) \\ 
    & = 3d \hspace{5mm} \text{for some integer $d$}
\end{align*}
```

Here's the result

[image: Result]

Why won't it center horizontally?

Comment: Looks centered to me.  But if you don't want the text to “count” in the centering, try using `\rlap` instead of `\text`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Yep, this was it! By centered, I meant I wanted the equations to be dead center with the text on the right. Thank you so much! You should enter this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`align` (rather TeX's display math setting) will take the whole equation as a single box, and horizontally center that in the text area.  This will include text that you insert in the equation with `\text`.

If you don't want that `\text` to be taken into account when TeX measures the equation, you can “hide” the width of the text with `\rlap`: `\rlap` will typeset the text in a box of zero width to the right of the current location (`\llap` will typeset to the left), effectively hiding the width of the text:

```latex
\begin{align*}
    a_{3k+3}  & = a_{3k+2} + 2a_{3k+1}  \\
    & = a_{3k+1} + 2a_{3k} + 2a_{3k + 1} \\
    & = 3a_{3k+1} + 2a_{3k} \\
    & = 3a_{3k+1} + 2(3m) \quad \rlap{(by the Induction Hypothesis)} \\ 
    & = 3(a_{3k+1} + 2m) \\ 
    & = 3d \quad \rlap{for some integer $d$}
\end{align*}
```

If you look at the output of `lua-visual-debug` you will see that the text isn't “seen” in the math boxes:

> [image]

---

Complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\begin{align*}
    a_{3k+3}  & = a_{3k+2} + 2a_{3k+1}  \\
    & = a_{3k+1} + 2a_{3k} + 2a_{3k + 1} \\
    & = 3a_{3k+1} + 2a_{3k} \\
    & = 3a_{3k+1} + 2(3m) \quad \rlap{(by the Induction Hypothesis)} \\ 
    & = 3(a_{3k+1} + 2m) \\ 
    & = 3d \quad \rlap{for some integer $d$}
\end{align*}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This made me learn so much of the inner workings of TeX! Thank you, you are LaTex GOD!!!

Comment: This is the kind of situation where I think: yes, the LaTeX way would be `\makebox[0pt][l]`, but `\rlap`is _soo_ much faster... `:-)`

Comment: @MohamedTlili Not by a long shot :-) But glad it was useful!

Comment: @campa I can count on a single hand how many times I used `\makebox` (directly) :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` all the way.